# Gradle settings and dependencies

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Imagine we have two projects:

```
root
 |
 |--MP
 |
 |--API
```

In these project `MP` use classes defined in API. I write `settings.gradle` file in the root directory:

```
include 'API', 'MP'
```

and build.gradle in that directory:

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin : 'java'

    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }

    version = '1.0'

    jar{
        manifest{
            attributes 'Gradle': 'Multiproject'
        }
    }
}
```

But if I don't create the following `build.gradle` in `MP`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':API')
}
```

it won't work. I thought `settings.gradle` define that we may use `API` in `MP` or vice versa during compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as designed. You have two subprojects and each of them has its own sources and dependencies. Applying the same customization using the `subprojects` closure doesn't merge them.